# Cannot retrive data from the database with first() Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My controller:

```
public function getNotificationApplication($user_id, $notification_id)
{
  $userdetails = Notification::with('user')->where(['user_id'=>$user_id])->first();
  $dataList = [];
  $dataList['notify'] = NotificationTypeA::with('notification')->where(['notification_id'=>$notification_id])->get();

  return view('Notification.notification_application', $userdetails, $dataList);
}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/notification_application/{user_id}/{notification_id}', 'NotificationController@getNotificationApplication')->name('show.notification_application');
```

my view:

```
@foreach ($userdetails as $userdetail)
  {{$userdetail->storage_location}}
@endforeach
```

When I am retrieving data from the database, I get a

> Undefined variable: userdetails

I can retrieve other variable ($data) that I am passing as an array, I can display them like this

```
@foreach ($notify as $notification)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $notification->item_name }} </td>
      <td>{{ $notification->risk_level }}</td>
      <td>{{ $notification->quantity }}</td>
      <td>{{ $notification->volume }}</td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

When I use

```
   `dd($userdetails);`
```

in the controller I get the correct data.

i have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Change it:

```
return view('Notification.notification_application', $userdetails, $dataList);
```

to

```
return view('Notification.notification_application', array('userdetails' => $userdetails, 'dataList' => $dataList));
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** The second parameter of `view()` is an array in which we can pass the `key` => `value` pair. And on view, we can get the data using the `key` passed in the array of second parameter of `view()`

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an array to the blade.

For that, you can use syntax as Mayank Pandeyz said or alternatively you can use`compact()` which will make code much cleaner.

```
return view('Notification.notification_application', compact('userdetails' ,'dataList'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Parth Vora and Mayank Pandeyz

i solved my problem combining both of their answers.

First of all i was passing 2 parameters one of which is an array the other is simply the first row of the table.

so i have to make a slight change in the controller

```
$userdetails['userdetails'] = Notification::with('user')->where(['user_id'=>$user_id])->first();
```

and then return

```
return view('Notification.notification_application', array('userdetails' => $userdetails), $dataList);
```

that did the trick..

thank you...

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following methods

1) `return view('Notification.notification_application', compact('userdetails' ,'dataList'));`

2) `return view('Notification.notification_application', ['userdetails' => $userdetails , 'dataList' => $dataList]);`

3)

```
return view('Notification.notification_application')
                ->with('userdetails', $userdetails)
                ->with('dataList, $dataList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in `return view` have two way :

```
 return view('Notification.notification_application', compact('userdetails','dataList'));
```

`OR`

```
return view('Notification.notification_application',
                    [
                      'userdetails'=>$userdetails,
                      'dataList'=>$dataList
                    ]);
```

Comment: this way give an error saying 
**Undefined variable: notify**

because the values that i am passing from the controller to the view are of 2 different kind as stated by @MayankPandeyz .. so in this case i have to do something like 

       `return view('Notification.notification_application', array('userdetails' => $userdetails), $dataList);`